# call batch file and run using its own path/directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, batch

I have a batch files that calls other batch files like this:

`e:\foo\master.bat` has the content:

```
call e:\bar\run1.bat
```

and `e:\bar\run1.bat` has the content

```
app1.exe
```

the problem is that when I run the `master.bat` `app1.exe` will not be executed, because it will expect it to be in the `e:\foo` directory instead of it being in `e:\bar` directory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are a bit unclear where app1.exe is located.

If it shares the folder with run1.bat change run1.bat

to either

```
@Echo off
Pushd "%~dp0"
app1.exe
popd
```

or

```
@Echo off
"%~dp0app1.exe"
```

`%0` refers to the currently running batch and the modifier `~dp` returns drive and path (with a trailing backslash.)

Comment: the `Pushd` method works best for me because, `app1.exe` internally also uses current dir, and using Pushd it will use the dir where `app1.exe` is located, without Pushd (but with the prefix) it will use the `master.bat` location

Comment: With this type of implications in mind, that method was the first in my answer intentionally. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question can be drawn from a similar question on Stack Overflow.

[What is the current directory in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file)

Using the variables mentioned here, you can update run1.bat to call app1.exe with the following line: `%~dp0app1.exe`. (The %~dp0 variable includes a trailing slash.) This will tell the batch file to run the executable from the current batch file's location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my universal script for executing a command in a specified
working directory:

```
CALL :EXEC_IN e:\bar run1.bat
```

The `EXEC_IN` batch-function is:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Execute a program inside a specified working directory
:: 1. Working directory
:: 2. Full file name
:: 3+ Arguments
:EXEC_IN
SETLOCAL

:: Scan fixed positional arguments:
SET  WD=%1&SHIFT
SET  FL=%1&SHIFT

:: Collect all arguments into %ALL%:
:EI_AA_START
IF [%1]==[] GOTO EI_AA_END
SET ALL=%ALL%%SEP%%1
SET SEP= 
SHIFT
GOTO :EI_AA_START
:EI_AA_END

:: Execute command %FL% in directory %WD% with args %ALL%:
PUSHD %WD%
CALL %FL% %ALL%
POPD
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B
```

If desired, feel free to modify it to take the working directory from
the file path intead of passing it as the first argument:

```
CALL :EXEC_IN_F e:\bar\run1.bat
```

This modified script is:

```
:: Execute a program with its location as working directory:
:: 1. Full path to the executable
:: 2+ Arguments
:EXEC_IN_F
SETLOCAL

:: Scan fixed positional arguments:
SET FL=%1
SET WD=%~p1
SHIFT

:: Collect all arguments into %ALL%:
:EI_AA_START
IF [%1]==[] GOTO EI_AA_END
SET ALL=%ALL%%SEP%%1
SET SEP= 
SHIFT
GOTO :EI_AA_START
:EI_AA_END

:: Execute command %FL% in directory %WD% with args %ALL%:
PUSHD %WD%
CALL %FL% %ALL%
POPD
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B
```